# Query builder with MongoClient in Micronaut application

Tags: java, mongodb-query, micronaut, micronaut-data

I am using the MongoClient with micronaut MongoDb. Trying to perform the query operators to create a query in mongoDb.

```
public static Bson QueryBuilder(ProductSearchCriteria productSearchCriteria){
        Bson query = null;
        if (productSearchCriteria.getName() != null){
         query = Filters.eq("name", productSearchCriteria.getName());
        }
        if(productSearchCriteria.getDescription() != null){
            query = Filters.eq("description", productSearchCriteria.getDescription());
        }
        return query;
    }
```

Now how can I perform logical AND/ OR / NOT / NOR and other operators in one query

Answer (score 0):

I did this, don't know if it is the correct way

```
public static List<Bson> QueryBuilder(ProductSearchCriteria productSearchCriteria){
        List<Bson> filters = new ArrayList<>();
        final BeanIntrospection<Product> introspection = BeanIntrospection.getIntrospection(Product.class);
        var product = introspection.getPropertyNames();

        if (productSearchCriteria.getName() != null){
            filters.add(Filters.eq(product[0], productSearchCriteria.getName()));
        }
        if(productSearchCriteria.getDescription() != null){
            filters.add(Filters.eq(product[2], productSearchCriteria.getDescription()));
        }
        return filters;
    }
```